# How can I messages between separate sections of one page?

Tags: php, html

Basically, in the following code:

```
<?php
$hostname = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$dbn = '';
try {
$dbh = mysqli_connect($hostname , $username, $password ,$dbn);
//echo 'Connected to database';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$password1 = $_POST['password1'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM User  WHERE Email = '$email1'";
$result_verify_email = mysqli_query($dbh, $query_verify_email);
if (!$result_verify_email) {//if the Query Failed ,similar to             if($result_verify_email==false)
echo ' Database Error Occured ';
}
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this     email .
// Create a unique  activation code:
$activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
//$id= uniqid();
$query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `User` ( `Name`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`,     `DOB`, `Activation`) VALUES ( '$fullname', '$username', '$email1', '$password1', '$dob',     '$activation')";
$result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbh, $query_insert_user);
if (!$result_insert_user) {
echo 'Query did not work ';
}
if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbh) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.
// Send the email:
$message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
$message .= 'http://website' . '/active.php?email=' . urlencode($email1) . "&key=$activation";
mail($email1, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From: a@b.com');
// Flush the buffered output.
// Finish the page:
echo '<div class="success">Thank you for registering! A confirmation email has been     sent to '.$email1.' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account </div>';
} else { // If it did not run OK.
echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system error. We     apologize for any inconvenience.</div>';
}
} else { // The email address is not available.
echo    '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email address has already been registered.
</div>';
}
mysqli_close($dbh);//Close the DB Connection
}// End of the main Submit conditional.
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="f1" action="Main.php" method="post">
        <p>Full name: <br/><input class="tb10" type="text" name="fullname" /></p>
        <p>Username: <br/><input class="tb10" type="text" id="username"     name="username" /><br/>
        <p>Email: <br/><input class="tb10" type="text" id="email1" name="email1" /></p>
        <p>Re-Enter Email: <br/><input class="tb10" type="text" name="email2" /></p>    <br/>
        <p>Password: <br/><input class="tb10" type="password" name="password1" /></p>
        <p>Re-Enter Password: <br/><input class="tb10" type="password" name="password2"     /></p><br/>
        <p>Date of Birth: <br/><input class="tb10" type="text" name="dob" /></br><img     src="img/calendar1.gif" alt="Calendar"     onclick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].dob,'yyyy/mm/dd',this)"/></p><br/>
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
        </div>                  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is I want to show the message that show up in the top (before the html part) in the body part. That means when the user completes the registration, the message will show up instead of the fields in the body section (Name, UserName, Email ,....).

To illustrate it:

If the registration is valid, I want the message:

```
Thank you for registering! A confirmation email has been     sent to '.$email1.' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account
```

Appears in the body part (instead of the fields).

I hope you understand my explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You set a variable, let it be `regSuccess`, in the php part to either true to false depending on whether user registration was successfull or not

Then in the html part, you checkk for the value of this variable in an `if` condition and output the corresponding html.

```
<?php
if($regSuccess == TRUE) {
?>
    Thank you message
<?php
} 
else 
{ ?>
    the input fields
<?php 
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you told me but I got another problem which is the calendar icon is not working!! A user is not able to browse the calendar !! can you help me with that

`<p>Date of Birth: <br/><input class="tb10" type="text" name="dob" /></br><img     src="img/calendar1.gif" alt="Calendar"     onclick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].dob,'yyyy/mm/dd',this)"/></p><br/>`

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) variable to indicate that the user successfully registered.  You will start a session on your page and check if that value is set before doing anything else.  If the variable exists, then display the activation message, otherwise provide the registration fields and continue with your existing code.

The reason for utilizing `$_SESSION` is to persist state information between page requests.

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['registered_email'])){

//Display message indicating user has already registered
echo 'Thank you for registering! A confirmation email has been sent to '. $_SESSION['registered_email'] .' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account';

}else{

// The rest of your code
...
// set session variable to indicate the registration was successful
$_SESSION['registered_email'] = $email1;
...
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create a variable to store you error message instead of echo it directly.
And add a 'IF' case in the `<body>` for validation occur error, echo the error, otherwise print the register form.